# Como criar um switch..case com faixas de valores?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, switch

Se um total de dias for maior que 30 e menor que 60, faço algo. Se for maior que 60 e menor 90 faço outra coisa e assim por diante. Como eu faço esse `case`? Será que o `case` é a melhor opção?

Comment: me explica uma coisa. O que seria "e assim por diante"? Você quer parar em que momento? Até 120? 150, 270, 300? Não entendi.

Comment: Dê exemplos do comportamento que você quer dentro de cada condição: de 30 até 60 o que será feito; de 60 até 90 o que será feito?

Answer (score 4):

Use `if` e `else if` dessa forma:

```
int dias = 60;

if (dias < 30)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("até 29");
}
else if (dias < 60)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("de 30 até 59");
}
else if (dias < 90)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("de 60 até 89");
}
else if (dias < 120)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("de 90 até 119");
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("acima de 120");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pergunta muito interessante, acabei de me deparar com este problema em um curso que estou fazendo.

Vi a solução de um colega aqui no fórum na linguagem Java:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = 534;
        switch (x / 200) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("entre 0 e 199");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("entre 200 e 399");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("entre 400 e 599");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("600 ou mais");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Deixo o link para quem tiver interesse, foi uma explicação muito clara.

[Usando Switch Case para intervalos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258024/usando-switch-case-para-intervalos)

A única alteração que eu tive que fazer no caso do C# foi capturar a parte inteira da divisão utilizando o método truncate.

[Math.Truncate Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=net-5.0)

O meu código ficou assim:

```
         switch (Math.Truncate(average/2)){

          case 0: // 0 a 1                
            generalConcept = Concepts.E;
            break;

          case 1: // 2 a 3
            generalConcept = Concepts.D;                
            break;

          case 2: // 4 a 5
            generalConcept = Concepts.C;                
            break;

          case 3: // 6 a 7
            generalConcept = Concepts.B;                
            break;

          default: // 8 ou mais
            generalConcept = Concepts.A;                
            break;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Desde o C# 8, foi introduzido os [Padrões relacionais](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#relational-patterns), o que permite que o `switch` inline faça atribuições com base na expressão da entrada e produz uma saída única.

```
// seu número em dias
int num = 35;

string resultado = num switch {
    > 0 and (< 30) => "menos que 30 dias e maior que zero",
    < 60           => "mais que 30 dias, menos que 60",
    <= 90          => "mais que 60, menos que 90",
    _              => "menor ou igual à zero, ou maior que 90"
};

Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

Leia a especificação do [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) ou veja o código acima [funcionando](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bn7jbp).

Note que o `_` funciona como o `default` do bloco `switch`, quando o valor não cai em nenhuma expressão. Quando você não o define, um alerta é indicado pelo compilador, e se você executar e um valor não cair em nenhuma condição, um erro do tipo `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SwitchExpressionException` é atirado.

Answer (score 1):

*⚠️**ALERTA**⚠️: Post antigo, sintaxes podem diferir entre diferentes versões da linguagem.*

##### $\textcolor{red}{\textsf{Color didint work .}}$

Tem várias maneiras.

**Switch**

Com `switch` essa é que vem à minha cabeça:

```
int mes = (int)System.Math.Floor((decimal)dias / 30);

switch(mes){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        // faz uma coisa
        break;
    case 2:
        // faz outra
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        // faz outra..
        break;
    default:
        // o padrao se nao safisfacoes nenhuma das outras regras
        break;
}
```

Claro, teria que ser visto antes se os intervalos são múltiplos de 30 e se são abertos ou fechados.

**If**

Com `If`, a mais óbvia seria:

```
if (dias > 30){
    if (dias < 60){
        // faz uma coisa
    }
    else if (dias < 90){
        // faz uma outra coisa
    }
    [...]
}
```

ou dependendo se for um comando:

```
var outputDeDias = EvalDias(dias);
    
private string EvalDias(int dias){
    if (dias < 30){
        return null;
    }
    if (dias < 60){
        return "uma coisa";
    }
    if (dias < 90){
        return "outra coisa";
    }
    [...]

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Não é legal retornar `null` quando o retorno do método não é anulável. Considere retornar uma `string?` quando seu método é capaz de retornar valores nulos.

Comment: @CyberPotato Olha a data... produto do seu tempo e ainda válido, a sintaxe em volta de `string & null` muda entre as várias versoes do C# e francamente nao tá no escopo da pergunta um "code smell"/"warning < 5 anos atrás".

Comment: Tem razão, não me atentei a este detalhe. Na época realmente não existia esse operador.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar vários `if`'s e não um `switch`. O switch serve para comparação de valores pontuais, não sendo capaz de comparar intervalos como você indicou na questão.

```
if (30 <= tempo && tempo < 60)
{
}
else if (60 <= tempo && tempo < 90)
{
}
```

Ai você vai aninhando os `if`'s nos `else`'s sucessivamente até onde precisar.

Comment: Realmente tem que ser por if. Assim vai tranquilo. Achei que por case daria, mas vi que não.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá. Se é "assim por diante", podemos escrever algo dessa forma.

```
  public void Tests(int diasInseridos)
    {
        int dias = diasInseridos;
        bool selected = false;//variavel que aciona um 'break' no momento em que entramos em alguma condição(if/else) válida
        int comparadorInicial = 30;//variavel comparadora de valor menor
        int comparadorFinal = 60;//variavel comparadora de valor maior

        while (selected == false)
        {
            if (dias == null || dias <= 0)
            {
                //Aqui retorna nenhum dia
                selected = true;//booleano para sair do laço
            }
            else if (dias > comparadorInicial && dias < comparadorFinal)
            {
                //Seu código retorna de acordo com os dias que seu programa detectou
                selected = true;//booleano para sair do laço
            }
            else
            {
                comparadorInicial = comparadorInicial + 30;
                comparadorFinal = comparadorFinal + 30;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu tive o mesmo problema em uma atividade na DIO com JavaScript, consegui resolver assim:

Você define o indicador como resultado booleano e analisa a variável nos case's e ele irá executar somente o verdadeiro.

Ex:

```
watts = 220
switch (true) {
case (watts < 100)
   console.log("Possui menos de 100 watts")
case (watts <= 200)
   console.log("Possui entre de 100 e 200 watts")
case (watts <= 300)
   console.log("Possui entre de 200 e 300 watts")
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Existem vantagens de usar o switch assim em relação ao if/else? Não esqueça dos `break` no código, senão o fogo se instaura no parquinho.