# Usando Switch Case para intervalos

Tags: java, switch, case

Tenho um exercício no qual devemos usar os cases de um `switch` para tratar intervalos, ele disse estritamente que devemos usar o `switch` e não podemos usar `if` e nem `while/do`. Já tentei o seguinte código:

```
switch(saldo){
    
        case 0..200:
            //...
        break;
}
```

Porém, sei que o Java não trabalha dessa forma, já pesquisei na internet um equivalente ao `..` e não achei nada que resolvesse o meu problema, há como fazer isso?

#### Enunciado:

> 4. Um banco concederá um crédito especial aos seus clientes, variável
>    com o saldo médio no último ano. Faça um algoritmo que leia o saldo
>    médio de um cliente e calcule o valor do crédito de acordo com a
>    tabela abaixo. Mostre uma mensagem informando o saldo médio e o valor
>    do crédito. (use o comando caso-de e não faça repetições)
>
> Saldo médio Percentual
>
> de 0 a 200 nenhum crédito
>
> de 201 a 400 20% do valor do saldo médio
>
> de 401 a 600 30% do valor do saldo médio
>
> acima de 601 40% do valor do saldo médio

Comment: Estes intervalos são o que ? Tempo?

Comment: Tem o enunciado disso? Não deu pra entender muito bem.

Comment: Não, esses intervalos são números inteiros. Por exemplo, caso o saldo >-1 e <201 eu faço algo, se > 200 é outra coisa, e assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pura matemática:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int x = 534;
        switch (x / 200) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("entre 0 e 199");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("entre 200 e 399");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("entre 400 e 599");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("600 ou mais");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eQrW6o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yvdmvkyo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/CaseRange.java).

A versão original não tinha o enunciado, mas o que muda é detalhe, o segredo é dividir pelo tamanho do intervalo.

Na verdade pelo enunciado é impossível, ou pelo menos muito complexo e teria que usar outro mecanismo auxiliar de tal forma que o `switch` será ruído, porque nem todos os intervalos são iguais, mas deve ser erro do enunciado, ajuda o fato de dizer "acima de 601" o que faria que o 601 ficasse no limbo. Dá para fazer ainda desde que crie um *array* auxiliar com os intervalos possíveis, ou neste caso mais simples tratar a exceção do primeiro caso (só ele parece ser diferente).

Algo assim:

```
((x == 0 ? 1 : x) - 1) / 200
```

Obviamente precisaria mudar os textos que eu usei.

A não ser que o professor queira que faça isto:

```
switch (x) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    .
    .
    .
case 200:
    System.out.println("entre 0 e 199");
    break;
case 201:
case 202:
case 203:
    .
    .
    .
case 400:
    System.out.println("entre 200 e 400");
    break;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Não seria a cada 200?

Comment: E está a cada 200. Na verdade com enunciado tão mal feito você não sabe qual é a real intenção.