# Definir variável de acordo com registro de número até número

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte ideia:

```
$quantidade = $rowcount;
if $quantidade (?) '(?)') {
$valor = '1';
```

Eu preciso definir o $valor seguindo:

```
de 100 a 499 = 1
de 500 a 999 = 2
de 1000 a 1499 = 3
de 1500 a 1999 = 4
de 2000 a 3999 = 5
acima de 4000 = quantidade*valor
```

Alguém podem me ajudar?

Comment: Essencialmente é isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258024/101

Comment: ta faltando um ( ai no if

Comment: Supondo que isso vem de um banco de dados, eu já traria calculado de lá, via SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obrigado** Inkeliz.

Eu acabai fazendo assim:

```
switch($quantidade) {
    case ($quantidade <= '100'): {
        $valor = '1';
        break;
    }
    case ($quantidade <= '500'): {
....

 default: {
        $valor = $rowcount*valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Então se for menor que 100 deve ser 1 também?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar um `if` e uma `array`, por exemplo:

```
if($quantidade >= 4000){
    echo $quantidade * 0.03;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 100) {
    echo [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5][(int)$quantidade/500];
}
```

Se o número for maior ou igual a 4000 irá multiplicar por 0.03. Se ele for menor que 4000 e maior que 100 ele irá pegar o valor da array, que é exatamente 1 até 5.

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente use **`if`**, que teria o mesmo efeito do seu `switch`, só que provavelmente o código ficaria um pouco menor (sem necessidade de `break` de `case`):

```
$valor = <valor inicial aqui>;
$quantidade = $rowcount;

if ($quantidade >= 4000) {
    $valor = $quantidade * $valor;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 2000) {
    $valor = 5;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 1500) {
    $valor = 4;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 1000) {
    $valor = 3;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 500) {
    $valor = 2;
} elseif ($quantidade >= 100) {
    $valor = 1;
} else {
    die('O valor inserido é menor que 100');
}

echo $valor;
```

Veja ficou até que bem legível e simples de compreender